# Extracting Multiple tar.gz files and copying the files present in sub directories into common folder

Tags: command-line, directory, tar, extract

I have multiple tar.gz files in 1 folder
In each tar.gz file, there are 2 folders named "Cscf & Cscf2", which further having 1 xml file each.

So my requirement is xml files present in Cscf folder gets copied to 1 common folder(ABC) and xml files present in Cscf2 folder gets copied in 1 common folder(XYZ)

Comment: Do the `*.xml` files have unique names? Read `man tar` - you can easily extract only the `*.xml` files,  and `mv` them anywhere you want.

Comment: find . -type f -name "*.gz" -exec tar xzf {} -C test \; this command did trick for me.

Comment: If you found a solution on your own, you are encouraged to create your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there are better solutions. But maybe it could be helpful for you until a better solution will appear, which you could accept. Run it in folder with your archives.

```
for arc in ./*.tar.gz; 
  do 
    tar xvf $arc && \
    mv $(echo $arc|sed 's/.tar.gz//')/Cscf/*.xml abc && \
    mv $(echo $arc|sed 's/.tar.gz//')/Cscf2/*.xml xyz  && \
    rm -r $(echo $arc|sed 's/.tar.gz//'); 
  done
```

- `arc` variable in `for` loop will keep each `.tar.gz` archive name
- `tar xvf $arc` will extract current archive
- `mv $(echo $arc|sed 's/.tar.gz//')/Cscf/*.xml abc` will move `.xml` files from extracted archive's `Cscf` folder into `abc` folder
- `rm -r $(echo $arc|sed 's/.tar.gz//')` will remove extracted folders